# How to show clickable buttons and sub buttons using flex property

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am new to web development, I am looking for a similar code to get the result as in the picture attached which is a responsive design with flex property of CSS. Once item1 is clicked the sub items should be visible and if we change the view to mobile they should be visible in a list. Does anyone has an idea about a similar code or can give me a hint. How to do it.

[image]

Comment: Similar to what code? You did not provide any. Please show some [reprex]...

Answer (score 1):

This should work on mobile devices and pc's (try run it from both devices):

```html
<div class='main'>
  <button id='mainbtn'>
    some button
  </button>
  <div class='btns' id='pcbtn' style='display:none;'>
    <button id='1'>
      sub1
    </button>
    <button id='2'>
      sub2
    </button>
    <button id='3'>
      sub3
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id='mobbtn' style='display:none'>
    <li>
      <ul>

        <button id='1'>
          sub1
        </button>
      </ul>
      <ul>

        <button id='2'>
          sub2
        </button>
      </ul>
      <ul>

        <button id='3'>
          sub3
        </button>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById('mainbtn').onclick = () => {
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      document.getElementById('mobbtn').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('pcbtn').style.display = 'flex';
    }
  }

</script>
```

I have a main div, which has 2 divs inside, 1 for pc, 1 for mobile devices, both have no display, if you are on pc, one of the divs (including its children, in our case it is the buttons) will display.